# Show image in excerpt post. Image not displaying

Tags: excerpt, thumbnails

I am editing a costum theme. I was trying to add excerpt to the homepage. The homepage is costum.

The excerpt show just fine but the image refuses to be displayed it seems.

This is my code:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => 3,4,5,6,7 );
$posts = query_posts( $args . '&orderby=date&order=desc' );
foreach( $posts as $post ) :    setup_postdata($post); ?>
<li>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="postcont">
        <?php 
        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Thumbnail", true);
        the_excerpt();  ?>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is of course added to functions.php

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}
```

Any toughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add support for Post Thumbnails, you can use its own function instead of `get_post_meta()`, see codex for more information - http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Function_Reference

Use following code in your theme:

```
<div class="postcont>        
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
    the_excerpt();
?>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

And using the OP's code:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => 3,4,5,6,7 );
$posts = query_posts( $args . '&orderby=date&order=desc' );
foreach( $posts as $post ) :    setup_postdata($post); ?>
<li>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="postcont">
        <?php 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        the_excerpt();  ?>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Chip for editing, I didn't have much time when writing this snippet. BTW @Jarco `query_posts()` is for modifying default query, if you want to get array of post for secondary listing use `get_posts()` function